# I made a function in python that finds the gcd of two numbers but it keeps returning none

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
#this file finds the gcd(a, b) using the euclidian algorithm
#uses the fact that, gcd(a, b) = gcd(rem(b,a), a)
def rem(a, b):
    if(a - b > b):
        rem(a-b, b)
    return a-b
#finds the gcd of a,b. Make sure a<b.
def gcd(a, b):
    if(a != 0):
        gcd(rem(b, a), a)
    else:
        print(a, b)
        return b

print(gcd(84, 126))
```

Here is what it outputs:

```
0 42
None
```

I'm confused because before the return statement it prints (a,b) and it prints out b as 42. But the return value on the next line is None. Can someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: `return gcd(rem(b, a), a)`, otherwise the return value is dropped on the floor. Likewise in `rem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit the `if` case in `gcd`, you aren't returning anything. If you add a `return` like this:

```py
def gcd(a, b):
    if(a != 0):
        return gcd(rem(b, a), a) # return here
    else:
        print(a, b)
        return b
```

you will get 42 as you expect, instead of `None`.

edit: I agree with user3840170's answer in the comments -- wasn't trying to copy that, I must have been formatting my answer while that was posted :)